# c# WPF ATM Application

Tags: c#, wpf

Need to include a condition to the below code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Command String", con);
            SqlDataReader readdata;

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                decimal balance = decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                decimal Balance = 0.00M;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Balance FROM Accounts";
                readdata = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (readdata.Read())
                {
                    Balance = decimal.Parse(readdata["Balance"].ToString());

                }
                con.Close();

                con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionstring");
                SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand("Command String", con);
                con.Open();

                if (Balance > balance)
                {

                    Balance -= balance;
                 cmda.CommandText = "UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = '" + Balance + "' ";

                    cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                    label2.Content = "Withdrawal Success";
                }
                else
                {
                    label2.Content = "Insufficient fund";

                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

For the above code the user can withdraw any amount from the balance but i need the condition to withdraw only 100's (100,200,300,etc.,)

Comment: Hint: Use modulo. Also, what if balance is sufficient but not a multiple of 100? Do you have an error message for this scenario?

Comment: This one works.

    if (Balance > balance)
                    {
                        if (balance % 100 == 0)
                        {
                            
                            Balance -= balance;
                     cmda.CommandText = "UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = '" + Balance + "' ";
                            
                            cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
                            con.Dispose();
                            label2.Content = "Withdrawal Success";
                        }
                        else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if (Balance > balance)` to `if (Balance > balance && balance % 100 == 0 )`.

Comment: The condition will work but replacing ==> if (Balance > balance) is not correct

Comment: Well, I was just using that as a quick example that gets the job done! Glad to help :)